# How to sort a string array in swift by number and letter values?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

I'm trying to sort an array that is listed as such:

```
let array = ["02:00 AM", "01:00 AM", "01:00 PM", "01:01 AM", "01:01 PM", "03:00 AM"]
```

It's a series of times that I can add/update in my userDefaults for reminders, however I want it sorted not only by the time but by the AM/PM value. that way the array looks like this:

```
["01:00 AM", "01:01 AM", "02:00 AM", "03:00 AM", "01:00 PM","01:01 PM"]
```

How can I do this? Using `.sort()` on the array doesn't work since that will just sort by time, but I specifically want the AM strings before the PM strings. I have the array as a String since I thought it would be easier, but I'm seeing that this may not be be best way about it.

Comment: One possible solution is to spilt the original array into two arrays, arrayAM and arrayPM, then sort them out in whatever order you want, and merge them back into a single array.

Comment: You should use real dates instead of strings considering daylight savings time issues. It will also allow you to sort them because `Date` conforms to `Comparable` protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @nighttalker 's answer you could get it in one line using `sorted(by: <)`.

Then the code would be:

```swift
let array = ["02:00 AM", "01:00 AM", "01:00 PM", "01:01 AM", "01:01 PM", "03:00 AM"]
let sortedArray = array.filter { $0.contains("AM") }.sorted(by: <) + array.filter { $0.contains("PM") }.sorted(by: <)
```

but as Arkku said you probably should use the Date type and make it conform to Comparable.

(I am not yet able to comment, so had to submit it this way)

Answer (score 0):

Filter by 12 & AM, then sort. Filter by 12 & PM, then sort. Then join the 2 arrays.

```
let array = ["12:00 AM", "12:02 PM", "02:00 AM", "01:00 AM", "01:00 PM", "01:01 AM", "01:01 PM", "03:00 AM"]
```

We need to consider that the #12 will impact sorting. So you need to filter out all times with 12, sort them, and place them in front.

```
let amc = array.filter { $0.hasPrefix("12") }.filter { $0.hasSuffix("AM") }.sorted(by: <) + array.filter { !$0.hasPrefix("12") }.filter { $0.hasSuffix("AM") }.sorted(by: <)
let pmc = array.filter { $0.hasPrefix("12") }.filter { $0.hasSuffix("PM") }.sorted(by: <) + array.filter { !$0.hasPrefix("12") }.filter { $0.hasSuffix("PM") }.sorted(by: <)
let comb = amc + pmc
print(comb) // prints ["12:00 AM", "01:00 AM", "01:01 AM", "02:00 AM", "03:00 AM", "12:02 PM", "01:00 PM", "01:01 PM"]
```

With this exercise, it's clear that using `Date` is the best approach.

Comment: Good point about the 12 AM vs 12 PM comparison – I'm accustomed to a 24-hour clock so I didn't realize 12:01 PM is really 00:01 PM for the purposes of sorting. (I think this is evidence that it would be better to use `Date` objects or such instead of strings.) Anyway, your current implementation of the 12 AM/PM is flawed: the minutes may also be 12, which matches the `.contains("12")`. It should be `.hasPrefix("12")`. Also, the handling of the `12:` case is broken: consider how `12:15` and `12:30` are sorted relative to one another.

Answer (score 0):

```
let morningTimes = arrayOfTimes.filter{$0.contains("AM") && !$0.contains("12:")}.sorted()
let dayTimes = arrayOfTimes.filter{$0.contains("12:") && $0.contains("AM")}.sorted() + morningTimes
let nightTimes = arrayOfTimes.filter{$0.contains("PM") && !$0.contains("12:")}.sorted()
let allTimes = dayTimes + arrayOfTimes.filter{$0.contains("12:") && $0.contains("PM")}.sorted() + nightTimes
```

Comment: Try with `["02:00 AM", "01:12 AM", "01:00 PM", "01:01 AM", "01:01 PM", "03:00 AM", "12:15 AM", "12:30 AM", "12:01 PM", "12:30 PM" ]` as the input. =)

Comment: Thanks for the constructive critique @Arkku Very helpful in me improving the solution

Answer (score -1):

You can pass `sort` a block and implement the comparison logic there, e.g.:

```
var array = ["02:00 AM", "01:12 AM", "01:00 PM", "01:01 AM", "01:01 PM", "03:00 AM", "12:15 AM", "12:30 AM", "12:01 PM", "12:30 PM" ]
array.sort { s1, s2 in
    let isAM1 = s1.contains("AM")
    let isAM2 = s2.contains("AM")
    return isAM1 && !isAM2 || ((isAM1 == isAM2) && s1 < s2)
}
```

The comparison block should return `true` if and only if the first argument is to be sorted before the second. This is implemented here such that either the first is AM and the second is PM, or both are the same AM/PM and the first has an earlier time.

P. S. You might consider using `Date` objects instead of strings in the first place (you can always format them back into strings as needed).

**Edit**: If your strings use the convention where "12:00 PM" is noon and "12:00 AM" is midnight, such times would be sorted incorrectly by the above. You can sort of fix that by testing for `s1.hasPrefix("12:")` and inverting the "is AM" status:

```
if s1.hasPrefix("12:") {
    isAM1 = !isAM1
}
if s2.hasPrefix("12:") {
    isAM2 = !isAM2
}
```

Even this approach sorts `12:59 AM` last instead of right before `01:00 AM` – you can fine-tune the comparison if this is an issue. However, I think this complexity alone is sufficient reason to use `Date` objects (or your own `Comparable` time holders) rather than strings. Assuming you are unwilling to switch to a 24-hour clock. =)

Comment: Downvotes would be more constructive if you were to explain what the problem is.